SHAP Summary with PLOTLY
I want to recreate the SHAP Summary Plot with the help of the plotly library.
I found this beautiful post: https://community.plotly.com/t/shap-like-bee-swarm-plots/68015
But I have no idea how the dataframe
df = pd.read_csv('Shap_FI.csv') 
was created.
This is the endresult:
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.read_csv('Shap_FI.csv')

#values = df.iloc[:,2:].columns
values = df.iloc[:,2:].abs().mean(axis=0).sort_values().index
df_plot = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['transaction_id', 'predictions'], value_vars=values, var_name='Feature', value_name='SHAP')

fig = px.strip(df_plot, x='SHAP', y='Feature', color='predictions', stripmode='overlay', height=4000, width=1000)
fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(showgrid=True, gridcolor='WhiteSmoke', zerolinecolor='Gainsboro'),
              yaxis=dict(showgrid=True, gridcolor='WhiteSmoke', zerolinecolor='Gainsboro')
)
fig.update_layout(plot_bgcolor='white')

fig = (
    fig
    # Make it so there is no gap between the supporting boxes
    .update_layout(boxgap=0)
    # Increase the jitter so it reaches the sides of the boxes
    .update_traces(jitter=1)
)

fig.write_html('plotly_beeswarm_test.html')
fig.show()


I am struggeling with the colour coding: Red and blue.In this post "Is there a way to recreate the Shap Values plot with plotly?" Is there a way to recreate the Shap Values plot with plotly? the colour code were just mapped to the classes which is not my goal.
And I do not understand this: transaction_id
